# Access globalState in Trigger

Tags: triggers, window, state, apache-flink

In a Flink window, can I access globalState in a trigger which is defined by myself?
I have tried the triggerContext.getPartitionedState, but it can only get the per-window state.

Comment: What do You mean by global state ?

Comment: it can be shared among all the windows, like the state got by ProcessWindowFunction.Context#globalState()

Comment: Wait, does Flink support global state?

Comment: oh, i made a mistake, the state accessed by ProcessWindowFunction.Context#globalState() is a keyed state in window operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only state available to a `Trigger` is the per-key, per-window state used via `triggerContext.getPartitionedState`. There is no global state for Triggers.

There are some possible workarounds. You could, conceivably, have a `Trigger` that fires on every event and then use global state in a `ProcessWindowFunction` to decide what to do (this is probably a very bad idea).

In most cases where it becomes difficult to get what you want from the window API it is better to build a thoroughly custom solution with a `ProcessFunction`. If it's not clear how to solve your problem that way, please ask another question that provides more details about your use case.